# How to save a value for the Get Request Using Views-Models

Tags: python, django, http

I am trying to create a chatbot, I want to create a variable(list/dictionary) the one which is one to save my GET Request, I want to access the value of the variable and manipulate it. After some logical operations, I will use a new variable to save a result and print that result on the same page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question. Your question at the moment is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you would want to have the logic of the chatbot, for example when the users type 'hi', the chatbot reply 'yes?'. The chatbot will be exposed through an API. Let the response of the API be in json format. You may use python's requests library to get the response from the api in dictionary by writing:

```
    receivedFromChatbox = response.json().
```